# How to use custom label color logically to a row chart in dc.js using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, graph, dc.js

How to use custom label color to a row chart in dc.js
my requirement is to show green and red color on the basis of some logical condition. I have tried 'pretransition' but not understand how to use it.

Can someone help me regarding this below is my code for rowchart.

Thanks in advance.

```
chart
    .width(768)
    .height(480)
    .elasticX(true)
    .label(function(d) return d.label)
    .dimension(runDimension)
    .group(speedSumGroup)
    .render();
```

Comment: You sound be able to use `colorAccessor` and `colors` (the color scale) for this. `pretransition` is for stuff not supported by the library already.

Comment: Oh... you said label color, not bar color. Indeed you would use `pretransition` for this, since the labels are not colored ordinarily. The coloring is easy; what's somewhat tricky is getting the data you need, since by default crossfilter only reduces one value per bin. So, if the logical condition comes from your source data, you will need a custom reduction that produces both a value and a logical value. Then `valueAccessor` to pull the value.